# Set priority for VB.NET events

Tags: vb.net, event-handling

I'm trying to create a program that creates a bunch of folders depending on an input and the matches with a database.
Everything works well, but I want to programmatically double-check that the right number of folders were created.

```
 Private Sub CreateButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CreateButton.Click
    Dim rows As DataRow()
    rows = dTable.Select(String.Format("[Pick List ID] = '{0}'", PLTextBox.Text))
    Dim sourcePath As String = ""
    Dim destPath As String = ""

    If rows.Count > 0 And PLTextBox.Text <> "" Then

        ' Some variable i want to use to count the number of folders created.
        folderCount = 0

        For Each row As DataRow In rows
            Try

            ...    
            some logic to specify what the sourcePath and destPath will be
            ...
                ' Checking if the directory exists
                If Not (Directory.Exists(destPath)) Then
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(destPath)
                End If

                ' Copy pasting source directory into newly created folder
                FileIO.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(sourcePath, destPath)

            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Error: " & ex.Message,, "Something went wrong...")
            End Try
        Next
```

So here, once all my folders are created, I want to verify that the right number was created, so in the same sub I have:

```
    RaiseEvent CreationDone(sender, e)

End Sub
```

To count my folder, I use:

```
    Private Sub FSWatcher_Created(sender As Object, e As FileSystemEventArgs) Handles FSWatcher.Created
        folderCount = folderCount + 1
    End Sub
```

And the CreationDone event is:

```
    Private Sub Creation_Done() Handles Me.CreationDone
        Dim rows As DataRow() = dTable.Select(String.Format("[Pick List ID] = '{0}'", PLTextBox.Text))
    If folderCount <> rows.Count Then
        MsgBox(folderCount & " folders were created. " & rows.Count & " were supposed to be created.",, "Error during the folder creation")

    Else
        MsgBox(rows.Count & " jobs were created",, "Success!")
    End If
End Sub
```

And the following happens: 
My `CreateButton_Click` handler runs, it raises the `CreationDone` event at the end, but the folder count is not updated because my `FileSystemWatcher` events are handled by `FSWatcher_Created` AFTER `CreateButton_Click` is done executing (so folderCount is still 0).

I tried to use an event to perform the check to that the order of events being raised and handled would be

- `CreateButton_Click` is run

for i = 1 to x folders to create

- 1 folder created
- `FSWatcher` raises 1 "created" events

next

- `CreationDone` event is raised
- `CreateButton_Click` ends
- x `FSWatcher.Created` events are handled
- `CreationDone` is handled

but the creationdone gets priority over the filesystem events.

How do I solve that?

**Interesting find (edit):**  When there is an exception thown during the folder copying process, the folderCount increments normally, so the exception are letting the `FSWatcher` raise events and/or my code handle them. Should I purposely throw an exception to make it work? (or maybe it just executes when i display a `msgBox` to display the error)

Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't set event priorities as far as I know. You would be better recording the names of folders that should be created while the code is running, and after is has completed, verify that they exist. This is better than using the FileSystemWatcher as there is a possibility if you are in a multi-threaded environment where other folders could be created in another thread.

Comment: Thanks, i just checked directory does not exist - create it - check directory exists :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your code, if you're trying to just get the count of folders for a specific directory you can do this:

```
  Dim folderCount as Integer = Directory.GetDirectories("YourPathway").Length
```